# Quickly remove outliers from list in Python?

Tags: python, list, outliers

I have a many long lists of time and temperature values, which has the following structure:

```
list1 = [[1, 72], [2, 72], [3, 73], [4, 72], [5, 74], [6, 73], [7, 71], [8, 92], [9, 73]]
```

Some of the time/temperature pairs are incorrect spikes in the data. For example, in time 8, it spiked to 92 degrees. I would like to get rid of these sudden jumps or dips in the temperature values.

To do this, I wrote the following code (I removed the stuff that isn't necessary and only copied the part that removes the spikes/outliers):

```
outlierpercent = 3

for i in values:
    temperature = i[1]
    index = values.index(i)
    if index > 0:
        prevtemp = values[index-1][1]
        pctdiff = (temperature/prevtemp - 1) * 100
        if abs(pctdiff) > outlierpercent:
            outliers.append(i)
```

While this works (where I can set the minimum percentage difference required for it to be considered a spike as `outlierpercent`), it takes a super long time (5-10 minutes per list). My lists are extremely long (around 5 million data points each), and I have hundreds of lists.

I was wondering if there was a much quicker way of doing this? My main concern here is time. There are other similar questions like this, however, they don't seem to be quite efficient for super long list of this structure, so I'm not sure how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: `index = values.index(i)` is making your code highly inefficient (and also it's potentially a bug). Use `for index, value in enumerate(values): ...`

Comment: A value gets also assigned to outliers if it returns back to normal. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Ronald Hi Roland, this is not intentional, however, it can be ignored (as most data points are redundant anyways). Unless there's a quick fix that doesn't cost any performance, no need to worry over these deletions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
outlierpercent = 3

for index in range(1, len(values)):
    temperature = values[index][1]
    prevtemp = values[index-1][1]

    pctdiff = (temperature/prevtemp - 1) * 100
    if abs(pctdiff) > outlierpercent:
        outliers.append(index)
```

This should do a lot better with time

Update:

The issue of only first outlier being removed is because after we remove an outlier, in the next iteration, we are comparing the temp from the removed outlier (`prevtemp = values[index-1][1]`).

I believe you can avoid that by handling the previous temp better. Something like this:

```
outlierpercent = 3
prevtemp = values[0][1]

for index in range(1, len(values)):
    temperature = values[index][1]

    pctdiff = (temperature/prevtemp - 1) * 100
    # outlier - add to list and don't update prev temp
    if abs(pctdiff) > outlierpercent:
        outliers.append(index)
    # valid temp, update prev temp
    else:
        prevtemp = values[index-1][1]
```

Comment: Mmm, apart from a the last line (it should be `append(index)` ), much time was saved by not appending `outliers.append([i, temp])` but `outliers.append(i)` only.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer! It works quite quickly (+1)! However, it seems that I have to run this multiple times to get rid of all outliers. Running once only gets rid of the first outlier for some reason. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: @Ronald: Thanks for pointing out the typo with i. It's updated now

Comment: @GeorgeOrwell: I have added an update. This should help you with fixing the issue. Also, do consider how you want to deal with the case where the 1st temp in `values` is actually an outlier.

Comment: @curious_guy: No problem, I tried to beat you in speed (which I almost did ;-) but I can't beat numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy to speed computations

With

```
values = [[1, 72], [2, 72], [3, 73], [4, 72], [5, 74], [6, 73], [7, 71], [8, 92], [9, 73]]
```

**Numpy Code**

```
# Convert list to Numpy array
a = np.array(values)

# Calculate absolute percent difference of temperature
b = np.diff(a[:, 1])*100/a[:-1, 1]

# List of outliers
outlier_indices = np.where(np.abs(b) > outlierpercent)
if outlier_indices:
  print(a[outlier_indices[0]+1])  # add one since b is is one short due to 
                                  # computing difference
 # Output: List of outliers same as original code
[[ 8 92]
 [ 9 73]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should make two lists, valid and outliers.

I tried to keep math operations to a minimum for speed.

Pardon any typos, this was keyboard composed, untested.

```
lolim=None
outliers=[]
outlierpercent=3.0
lower_mult=(100.0-outlierpercent)/100.0
upper_mult=(100.0+outlierpercent)/100.0
for index,temp in values
    if lolim is None:
         valids=[[index,temp]]            # start the valid list
         lolim,hilim=[lower_mult,upper_mult]*temp  # create initial range
    else:
         if lolim <= temp <= hilim:
             valids.append([index,temp])               # new valid entry
             lolim,hilim=[lower_mult,upper_mult]*temp  # update range
         else:
             outliers.append([index,temp])             # save outliers, keep old range
```